# Ionic 3 i18n translation on iOS WKWebview

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I am not able to get translation data from my .json file after upgrading to WKWebview. It is working perfectly fine in browser but when I deploy it in device, it doesn't work.

My app.module.ts

```
import {
  HttpClientModule,
  HttpClient,
  HTTP_INTERCEPTORS
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from "@ngx-translate/http-loader";
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    PopoverComponent,
    LimitToDirective,
    ImageModalPage,
    PaymentPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    FormsModule,
    IonicImageLoader.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
   ...

  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ]
})

export class AppModule {}

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {

  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "assets/i18n/", ".json");
}
```

Translate init method

```
 initTranslate() {
    this.translate.use("en");
  }
```

Calling methods

```
<div class="primaryLabel">{{ "commons.version" | translate }}</div>
```

```
translate.get("commons").subscribe(val => {
      console.log(val)
      this.headerTitle = val.title;
    });
```

My en.json file

```
{
"commons": {
        "title": "XXXXX",
        "logout": "Logout",
        "confirmLogout": "Are you sure you want to logout ?",
        "currency": "SAR",
        "version": "Version",
        "updateProfile": "Update Profile",
        "faq": "FAQ"
    }
}
```

console.log(val) gives output as "commons".

Comment: did you got any solution?

Comment: try this https://github.com/TheMattRay/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix

Comment: any news? i'm facing the same problema with an old app

Answer (score 0):

Add the `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr` Plugin to your project and it should work again:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr
```